# BlueScreen[Error : 0x0000003b / c0000005] Reading bytes from SerialPort

Tags: c#, serial-port, blue-screen-of-death

i have a BarcodeScanner here which im telling to make a picture for me.
Im sending a command as byte to the scanner, waiting for the response and then im trying to read it.

if i just use a serial monitor and send the bytes manually it works just fine, i get my whole jpeg and im happy.

if i try it in C# i try to read the bytes with a simple method (was the bread and butter method which i found on google. normal i used (serialport.ReadExisting() which crashes the same way).

here is the whole event :

```
 public void serial_datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                usescanner = (SerialPort)sender;
                if (sender is SerialPort)
                {
                    string port = ((SerialPort)sender).PortName;
                    int count = ((SerialPort)sender).BytesToRead;
                    int returnAscii = 0;
                    string message = "";
                    while (count > 0)
                    {
                        returnAscii = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadByte();
                        message = message + Convert.ToChar(returnAscii);
                        count--;
                    }
                    ScanPort sport = new ScanPort(port, true);
                    scanner.ScannerPort = sport;
                }

            ((SerialPort)sender).Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

i *Always* get 4096 bytes to read back. and then i can read till about 70-90 bytes so yes my messagestring is that long then so it does work ! just simply crashes in the middle of it.

the scanner is not the problem as im working with the scanner for a long time. and i can send data back and forth. also ive tested it on a demoprogram which the manufacturer handed me so it does work.

any ideas? maybe i just dont know how to read bytes.

thanks for the help

Comment: What line throws that error?  You have some weird casting going on, my guess is you casted something incorrectly.

Comment: The Castin is correct, the sender is the SerialPort so i just take the Port which is receiving data and Using it as a SerialPort which it is. I also am Reading bytes, its just at a certain port the bluescreen gets me. which i doesnt understand, i am asking for bytestoread, and in a serial port monitor (ext program) i see my whole string which i am reading out, but at a certain point it just crashes my whole pc

Answer (score 0):

You set `usescanner` as your SerialPort but then you continue to call `((SerialPort)sender)` throughout the code and don't reference `usescanner`.  What was the point of setting it?

Anywho, you should just setup a very simple example and see if you can get the error to happen.  Sometimes when you add too much complicated code its hard to find the issue. 
 I recommend going simple to prove that is the problem and not your code. Create a new form with a open button and a close button.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    SerialPort sp;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);  //initialize our serial port
        sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived); //create our data received event
        sp.Open(); //Open the port
    }

    void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Data = sp.ReadExisting();

        Console.Write(Data);
    }

    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Close(); //close the port
    }
}
```